# List reorder and Encoding

Tags: python, list

My question is

1. If i have a  list of strings that have an odd number of elements and want to reorder it this way :- taking the very first element then the very last one , then the second from the beginning and the second from the last and so on

EX:

[ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']

i want it

[ 'a' , 'e' , 'b' , 'd' , 'c']

Comment: 2nd is not an issue, you are just seeing the `repr` output of the strings. For first did you try anything, should be simple

Comment: sorry im sure you made an effort but I dont quite understand what you are asking ...

Comment: clarify 1st question please

Comment: thanks  Anan S Kumar for reply

Comment: thanks  Anan S Kumar for reply, i deleted the 2nd question and  edited the 2nd one to be about lists of  odd number of elements ,i did it with lists of even number elements but still not with odd one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it doesn't matter if the list is even or odd.

```
def sortList(sortMe):
    tmp = []
    for i in xrange(len(sortMe)):
        tmp.append(sortMe[i])
        tmp.append(sortMe[len(sortMe)-(i+1)])
    return tmp[:len(sortMe)]

print(sortList(['a','b','c','d','e','f']))
```